# how to change the only one row background in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, row, cell, background-color

I'm going to change the background color of the row based column value.

At first loading of table, It's done by rowattr.

After edit the column, how can I change the row background based on the column without reloading the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known problem of editing of data. The solution depends on the version and fork of jqGrid, which one use, or from the editing mode used.

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, then one can use `afterSetRow` callback, which will be called after *any* changing of the row (inline or form editing). The following code of `afterSetRow`

```
afterSetRow: function (options) {
    if (options.localData.closed) {
        $(options.tr).addClass("ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
    } else {
        $(options.tr).removeClass("ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
    }
}
```

can be used additional to `rowattr`

```
rowattr: function (item) {
    if (item.closed) {
        return {
            "class": "ui-state-error ui-state-error-text"
        };
    }
}
```

See the demo https://jsfiddle.net/k5j2ojx2/. You can try to edit the row with respect of inline editing buttons (`fomatter: "actions"`), by form editing or inline editing buttons of navigator bar (added by `navGrid` and `inlineNav`). If you would change the checkbox of `Closed` column then the color of the row will be changed too.

**UPDATED:** If you use *cell editing* then you should use `afterSaveCell` callback. For example,

```
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, name, value, iRow, iCol) {
    if (name === "closed") {
        if (value === "true") {
            $(this.rows[iRow]).addClass("ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
        } else {
            $(this.rows[iRow]).removeClass("ui-state-error ui-state-error-text");
        }
    }
}
```

see https://jsfiddle.net/k5j2ojx2/1/

Comment: Hi Oleg,
It seems that afterSetRow is not called after afterSaveCell function.
Can I update the row's background on afterSaveCell?

Comment: @danielparker: You should describe your problem **more detailed**. For example, all editing modes (inline editing, form editing and cell editing) use own callbacks/events. `afterSaveCell` be called in case of **cell editing**. Cell editing works with cells and not rows and it doesn't call `setRowData` (thus `afterSetRow` will be not called too). See **UPDATED** part of my answer for the solution in case of cell editing.